# Moving all files from documents/inbox to documents in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory

I have an iOS app, and I've implemented the "Open in" function into my app for .plist files. Everything works perfectly, except that when I import .plist files, they end up in documents/inbox instead of in the regular documents folder. Is there a way to change it to show up in the documents folder instead of in the inbox folder, or to move them? I'm currently using the following code, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The code is from the 3rd reply on [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/59909-how-to-copy-a-file-from-one-folder-in-document-directory-to-document-directory.html) page.

```
//get to inbox directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *inboxContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@";%@/Inbox", documentsDirectory] error:nil];

//move all the files over
for (int i = 0; i != [inboxContents count]; i++) {
    NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@";%@/Inbox/@%", documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@";%@", documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
}
```

If it's possible, I'd also like to clear out the inbox folder once all the files are transferred, but it's not a priority, as the plist files tend to be very small.

EDIT: I found out (with user originaluser2's suggestion of using breakpoints) that my app was not correctly picking up the directories, so I changed the code so that it picks up strings that are preset. Here's the current code in viewDidLoad

```
//Turn every file inside the directory into an array
// Note to self: remember to actually put files in the Documents folder. Use the code in the apparopriately marked file
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//strings to actually get the directories
NSString *appFolderPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inboxAppFolderPath = [appFolderPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Inbox"]; //add ".plist" to the end of the recipe name


//predicates to hide unwanted files 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF beginswith[c] '.DS_Store'"];
NSPredicate *inboxPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not SELF beginswith[c] 'Inbox'"];
recipes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:appFolderPath error:nil];
recipes = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
recipes = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inboxPredicate];




//move all files from inbox to documents root
//get to inbox directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *inboxContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:inboxAppFolderPath, documentsDirectory] error:nil];

//move all the files over
for (int i = 0; i != [inboxContents count]; i++) {
    NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:inboxAppFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:appFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:nil];
}
//end of moving all files
```

With this code, the app correctly views the directories and can tell me which files are in the Inbox folder, but does not actually transfer its contents over to the Documents folder.

Comment: why do you have a semi-colon in `stringWithFormat:@";%@/Inbox"`?

Comment: @originaluser2 I'm not quite sure (the page I referenced said to put them in), but even when removing the semicolons, nothing happens...

Comment: have you tried using breakpoints to isolate the exact source of the problem? Is it failing to retrieve the contents of the inbox? Is is failing to move them?

Comment: @originaluser2 I used some breakpoints, and discovered that it wasn't picking up the oldPath or newPath, so I changed them to NSStrings (I'll add an edit in a bit to show all the new code). Now it picks up all the directory names properly, but it's not actually moving the files from the Inbox folder to the Documents folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your paths that you define:

```
NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:inboxAppFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:appFolderPath, documentsDirectory, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
```

After providing an `NSError` to the `moveItemAtPath:` method, it returned the error:

```
2016-01-19 08:43:57.534 Moving Files[35505:9385200] error: “Inbox” couldn’t be moved to “E70C5B67-D502-4C06-B480-03675E35E999” because an item with the same name already exists.
```

**What's happening is your string formatting is incorrect, as it's only taking the first argument you provide, which is the Inbox folder path (not the file path from within the Inbox folder).**

You simply want to change your path definitions to the following:

```
NSString *oldPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", inboxAppFolderPath, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
NSString *newPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", appFolderPath, [inboxContents objectAtIndex:i]];
```

That should fix the problem.

**Remember in the future, if ever you're having problems with `NSFileManager`, always try and get the error from it:**

```
NSError* error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
```

Comment: Can you please give the code for Swift 5 . I am facing a lot of trouble for it.